# Запустить Vue-cli offline без установки

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-cli

Необходимо перенести проект vue.js на сервер, где нет доступа к интернету и нельзя поставить vue-cli. На сервере есть npm 6.4.1 и node js 8.12.0.
Проект перенес с папкой node-modules, там находятся все зависимости (также папка @vue, vue-client-server).
При запуске билда через npm run server (где serve это vue-cli-service serve) пишет, что vue-cli-service не найдена. 
Как оффлайн установить vue-cli-service при наличии его в папке node-modules в проекте или можно ли использовать другую команду для запуска?

Comment: я думаю, что для начала необходимо скопировать необходимые пакеты, в ту папку, где расположены глобально установленные пакеты в Вашей системе. Узнать это можно с помощью команды `npm root -g` . А дальше - по ситуации

Comment: Скопировал, это не помогло, так как все еще не видит команду vue-cli-service serve. также нет прав администратора, npm root -g показывает пользовательскую папку моего аккаунта (а не ту, где установлен node js).